# Brown Blob in natural maple syrup?

Tags: syrup

I was pouring out  my natural maple syrup today and found gelatinous dark brown blob in it. This syrup was stored in the refrigerator in a large plastic bottle. It is not past date on the bottle. Once I pulled this blob out it would not rinse down through my sink strainer very well. What is this blob and is my syrup still good?

Answer (score 2):

Maple syrup can develop a skin of mold but a number of afficianados suggest removing the mold then reboiling the syrup and then continuing to use the syrup:

[Chowhound.com maple syrup mold growth discussion](http://chowhound.chow.com/topics/575573)